# Como fazer upload por FTP ao invés de HTTP

Tags: php, ftp

Eu preciso mandar arquivos acima de 2GB, e acabei lendo que é melhor usar FTP, pesquisei um pouco e consegui esse código:

uploadFTP.php

```
<?php
    set_time_limit(0);
    $server_ftp = 'xx.xx.xxx.xxx';

    $usuario_ftp = SQL_USUARIO;
    $senha_ftp   = SQL_SENHA;

    $limitar_tamanho = 0;

    $arquivo = $_FILES['arquivo'];
    $nome_arquivo = $arquivo['name'];
    $tamanho_arquivo = $arquivo['size'];
    $arquivo_temp = $arquivo['tmp_name'];

    $destino = DIR_ARQUIVOS.$nome_arquivo;

    $conn_ftp = ftp_connect($server_ftp);
    $login_ftp = @ftp_login($conn_ftp, $usuario_ftp, $senha_ftp);

    if (!$login_ftp){exit('Usuário ou senha FTP incorretos.');}

    if (@ftp_put($conn_ftp, $destino, $arquivo_temp, FTP_BINARY)) 
    {
        echo 'Arquivo enviado com sucesso!';
    } else {echo 'Erro ao enviar arquivo!'; }

    // Fecha a conexão FTP
    ftp_close( $conn_ftp );
```

O problema é que no meu caso, eu tenho um form(`POST`) com um `<input type="file">` que eu uso `if(isset($_POST['fileInputName']))` desta forma para mover(`move_uploaded_file`) o arquivo que foi feito upload, porém eu gostaria de uma forma de fazer esse upload (de vários arquivos no mesmo input) pelo código FTP acima, e ainda sim poder usar o `isset`.

Comment: Cara, dei uma resposta, mas acabei respondendo apenas o final da pergunta (é bom evitar fazer mais de uma pergunta diferente na mesma questão).

Answer (score 0):

Cara, coloca um atributo `name` nos `inputs` que siga um padrão. Por exemplo:

```
<input type="file" name="arquivo_1" />
<input type="file" name="arquivo_2" />
<input type="file" name="arquivo_3" />
```

Depois, faz um loop pra ver se você acha esses caras no seu `POST`:

```
$ix = 1;
while( isset($_POST["arquivo_$ix"]) )
{
  ...
  $ix++;
}
```